# How can I recover my Yahoo account when I don't remember the security question?

Tags: yahoo

I have had a Yahoo email address for a long time but have not used for a while.

I want to sign into Yahoo now, but it asks me a security question. I have forgotten the answer to this security question.

I know my user name and password, but I can’t sign in without answering the security question. Is there any way to sign in without the security question?

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have an alternate email address listed with your Yahoo account you may be able to get a link to reset your password sent to that alternate email address.
See [Recovering a lost or forgotten password](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SLN2047&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1388560952860&locale=en_US&y=PROD_MAIL_ML) on the Yahoo help pages for more info.